# Google recaptcha v2 verification in php - null response

Tags: php, recaptcha

I have been using recaptcha v2 across a number of php sites for the last few months. recently they have all stopped working. The admin page states "We detected that your site is not verifying reCAPTCHA solutions". I have not changed any of my code in this time so surely the issue is not with that, and I can see that I am still capturing the user response successfully, but I am at a loss as to what I can do to get the forms working again. I have tried recreating new keys for one of the sites but that made no difference.  Has anyone else experienced this?  This is the relevant verification code I am using...

```
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $secretKey = 'the-key-I-was-given';
    $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

    if(!$captcha){
      header('Location: nocheck.html');
      exit;
    }

    $mail_to = "my-email-address";
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $email_from = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = "Message from ....";
    $email_body = "You have received a new message from $name.\n".
     "Here is the message:\n\n $message\n\n";

    if ( empty($email_from) OR !filter_var($email_from, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) OR empty($subject) OR empty($email_body)) {
        http_response_code(400);
        echo '<p class="alert alert-warning">Please complete all fields on the form and try again.</p>';
        exit;
    }

    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $responsedata=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$ip);
    $responseKeys = json_decode($responsedata,true);

    if(intval($responseKeys["success"]) !== 1) {
      echo '<p class="alert alert-warning">Oops! Captcha verification has failed. Please email me instead at my-email-address. Thank you.</p>';
    } else {
```

The response seems to be 0 every time -  so triggering the verification failed error.  Any pointers gratefully accepted thanks.

Comment: Start by checking what the API call _actually_ returns …

Comment: It appears to return nothing at all.

Comment: file_get_contents returns just false, if the HTTP status code of the response indicated an error. What do you get when you try to call that exact same URL directly in your browser then …?

Comment: The browser call returns   "invalid-input-response" and invalid-input-secret". So that helps I guess, but the secret key and user response inputted is definitely correct

Comment: @04FS Incidentally although on several of my sites this has stopped working,I have the exact same code on one other site which is still working fine - only difference is the ISP. Could there be something that the ISP has done to affect these responses?

Comment: That is very unlikely. Plus, it is an HTTPS request, those are hard to “interfere“ with without the receiving end noticing. Maybe rather a server configuration issue? If you had `allow_url_fopen` disabled, then file_get_contents would not be allowed to make this request in the first place.

Comment: Thanks - you have given me some avenues to work on!

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar problem. I changed host 2 weeks ago and the same ReCAPTCHA code no longer works. I also get the same message in the Recaptcha Admin Console "We detected that your site isn't verifying reCAPTCHA solutions. This is required for the proper use of reCAPTCHA on your site. Please see our [developer site](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify#api-request) for more information."

I think that link to the Google Developers is important but I can't work what to do.
Are you (Mark) downloading the error log from the server?
It is generated in the root folder after every ReCaptcha failure. I download it via FTP and read the latest error. I have had the following 5 errors a lot.

```html
[12-Jan-2020] Error 1: PHP Warning:  require_once(cgi-bin/ReCaptcha.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /public_html/submit2.php on line 2
```

Me: I thought my file paths were wrong but I changed them and nothing happened, I think I will try that again.
i.e. Ln 2: require_once('cgi-bin/ReCaptcha.php'); changed to
Ln 2: require_once('/cgi-bin/ReCaptcha.php'); didn't work.

[12-Jan-2020] Error 2: PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'cgi-bin/ReCaptcha.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/share/pear') in /public_html/submit2.php on line 2
Me:No idea why it was looking there? Line 2 of submit2.php is the example above.

[13-Jan-2020 00:00:55 UTC] Error 3: PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in /public_html/cgi-bin/Post.php on line 68
Me:Line 68 of Post.php reads:
return file_get_contents(self::SITE_VERIFY_URL, false, $context);
allow_url_fopen was mentioned by 04FS but I don't know what he meant.

[13-Jan-2020 00:00:55 UTC] Error 4: PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /public_html/cgi-bin/Post.php on line 68
Me: Line 68 again...

[14-Jan-2020 02:53:18 UTC] Error 5: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$secret' (T_VARIABLE) in /public_html/submit2.php on line 11
Me: This was my mistake - a missing semi-colon after the secret key (after I made new keys today) also a fail after I fixed it.

I hope this helps, sorry if it doesn't. If I get it to work I will post again.

Comment: Thatchman you have the same symptoms certainly. what do you get back from a call in your browser to the API? I have worked through the info on the Google Recaptcha Developer Site as suggested but still get the same error.  I am waiting on a response from my ISP on this too in case they can shed any light on it.  as I my code works fine on another site with another ISP, and pobviously was working fine until very recently with this ISP.  Will post here if I make any progress.

Comment: Hi Mark, I get the error I have written in the submit.php file after the key comparison and response capture BUT as suggested previously, when I entered the URL appended with submit.php...I get the same thing.

Comment: I believe I solved my problem by uploading the .php test file containing 
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
see https://celebrantsue.com/phptest.php
which showed the directive allow_url_fopen was OFF.
see `https://celebrantsue.com/phptest.php`
 I asked hosting support to turn it on and they refused saying it was a HUGE security risk...So for the time being I have taken reCAPTCHA off the forms and given up...until I try another reCAPTCHA version...

Comment: Got a response from my ISP - nothing they have done to stop captcha working. So I too will have to remove captcha from my sites, as I cannot work this out.